# How can I stop the Moveit planning execution when there is a collsion between the robot and the object in the scene?

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have successfully introduced collision objects in the Moveit planning scene. The collision objects are real objects detected with a ZED camera and they are in the Moveit simulation as can see from this code and RVIZ screenshot.
Here the collision objects code

```
using namespace sensor_msgs;
using namespace std;

void chatterCallback(const darknet_ros_3d_msgs::BoundingBoxes3d& boxes)
{ 
         
 int counter_id = 0;
 const std::string PLANNING_GROUP = "crane_control";    
 moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface;
 std::vector<std::string> object_ids;
 moveit_msgs::CollisionObject collision_object;
 collision_object.header.frame_id = "world";
 collision_object.id = "BOX_";
 std::vector<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject> collision_objects;
                                 
          for(auto bb : boxes.bounding_boxes)
                    {
                    
                                  shape_msgs::SolidPrimitive primitive;
                                  primitive.type = primitive.BOX;
                                  primitive.dimensions.resize(3);
                                  string str= to_string(counter_id++);
                                  
                                  //Pose
                                  geometry_msgs::Pose box_pose;
                                  box_pose.position.x = abs ((bb.xmax + bb.xmin)/2);
                                  box_pose.position.y = abs ((bb.ymax + bb.ymin)/2);
                                  box_pose.position.z = abs ((bb.zmax + bb.zmin)/2)-10;
                                  box_pose.orientation.x = 0; 
                                  box_pose.orientation.y = 0;   
                                  box_pose.orientation.z = 0;
                                  box_pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
                                
                                  //Dimension
                                  primitive.dimensions[0] = abs (bb.xmax - bb.xmin);
                                  primitive.dimensions[1] = abs (bb.ymax - bb.ymin);
                                  primitive.dimensions[2] = abs (bb.zmax - bb.zmin); 
                                  
                                  //Collision objects                                                                                                                               
                                  collision_object.primitives.push_back(primitive);
                                  collision_object.primitive_poses.push_back(box_pose);                                                                   
                                  collision_objects.push_back(collision_object); 
                                  sleep(0.5);                                                        

                            }
                                 collision_object.operation = collision_object.REMOVE; 
                                 object_ids.push_back(collision_object.id);
                                 planning_scene_interface.removeCollisionObjects(object_ids); 
                                 sleep(0.3); 
                                 collision_object.operation = collision_object.ADD;
                                 planning_scene_interface.applyCollisionObjects(collision_objects);

 }

int main(int argc,  char** argv)

{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "cpp_subscriber");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/darknet_ros_3d/bounding_boxes", 5, chatterCallback);
  ros::spin();  
  
}
```

Here can see the collision object with RVIZ
[image: RVIZ]

So,  now first I would like to give the robot a path-goal from point A to B  and then when is in the collision with the object just to stop. Any Help?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374887/how-can-i-stop-the-moveit-planning-execution-when-there-is-a-collsion-between-the-robot-and-the-object-in-the-scene?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2021-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure I understood your pipeline completely (what's a "path-goal"?), but:

1. If you set a pose goal and requested a motion plan, your path will not be in collision that are currently in the scene.
2. If you are requesting a cartesian path, the current interface returns the up to the first collision.
3. If you are detecting collision objects while moving, IIRC the `Replanning` checkbox in the Motion Planning plugin is supposed to keep checking the trajectory for collisions and replan when it finds a collision in the remaining path. You could take a look at and change this functionality to just stop.
4. If "path-goal" means that you already have a trajectory and you want to check it for collisions in your current scene, you can use the `isPathValid` functions in the [PlanningScene](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/moveit_core/html/classplanning__scene_1_1PlanningScene.html) API.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-29**:
And a general comment: you might want to move the initialisation of the `PlanningSceneInterface` and related infrastructure to somewhere *outside* the callback. The code as-is leads to (potentially) high-frequency creation and destruction of objects with a high cost to that creation and destruction. That's far from optimal, and will likely influence application performance quite a bit.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-03-29**:
"Path-goal " , sorry I mean navigate the robot from a point A to B. In my case the tower crane (the load is moving from point A to B and in that way I want to introduce the collision object and make the robot(tower crane) stop. Hope now more clear

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-03-29**:
Like where to move the initialization of the PlanningSceneInterface and related infrastructure to somewhere outside the callback? Then what will be in the callback?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-03-29**:
It's not clear to me at what time you add the collision object to the scene. If it's before the planning starts, then you should be fine. If it's during movement (during execution of the trajectory) then you need to take some extra care.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-03-29**:
It's during movement. So how to proceed in this case? Which of your 4 statements can be used ?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-03-29**:
Mainly 3. I haven't looked at that part of the code in detail, but I know that your use case was the intention behind it. Have a look at `plan_execution.cpp` and the replanning flag.

You could also use 4 to check for collisions when you detect new collision objects, and stop the execution yourself.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-03-29**:
Is it in Motion Planning Pipeline? This one [http://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/motion_planning_pipeline/motion_planning_pipeline_tutorial.htm](http://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/motion_planning_pipeline/motion_planning_pipeline_tutorial.html)l

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-03-29**:
It's [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_ros/planning/plan_execution/src/plan_execution.cpp). Watch out that you're not looking at outdated tutorials (you linked to Kinetic). Also please accept this answer so it's out of the queue.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-03-29**:
I can not see the replanning flag. Please can you point it out in the  `plan_execution.cp`?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-03-29**:
It is in the [move_group_interface](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L1061) and in the RViz plugin. I recommend downloading the repository and searching through all files to get a better idea of the code (try VSCode and Ctrl-Shift-F).

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-03-29**:
ok. Got it. Thanks. Only one more thing about the [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/)  comment"to move initialisation of the PlanningSceneInterface and related infrastructure to somewhere outside the callback" Where should I move it? In the main or some Public or private class?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-03-29**:
I would keep the PSI as a member variable of a class.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-03-29**:
ok got thanks

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-04-18**:
Sorry, one more thing. I realize that `plan_execution.cpp`  is not in [move_group_interface](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L1061) . So confusing, which repository to download. Please can you tell me exactly? Because `plan_execution.cpp` is in [plan_execution](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_ros/planning/plan_execution/src/plan_execution.cpp). Am I missing something?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-04-18**:
All of those files are in the MoveIt repository. The `replan` flag is [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L1061) in the MoveGroupInterface, as I mentioned. It is sent to the move_action_client [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L847), which is received [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_ros/move_group/src/default_capabilities/move_action_capability.cpp#L63), and then executed [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_ros/move_group/src/default_capabilities/move_action_capability.cpp#L155), which refers to the code in `plan_execution`. It's not a straight forward structure, but it will be easier if you set up your IDE to navigate the codebase.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-04-19**:
Ok thats why better use VSCode and navigate through it with Ctrl-Shift-F, right?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-04-19**:
You can set it up so that you can Ctrl-Click on functions. See the tutorials for VSCode and its ROS extension.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-04-21**:
Sorry , so for my understanding I need to write four nodes (4 .cpp nodes) for the `replan` flag, move_action_client, receiving, and executing accordingly? Is that correct?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-04-21**:
No, please read about how the move_group works and post a proper question about it if you need more help.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-04-23**:
Ok. I will post a proper question as i need a more help

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-04-27**:
so, can I ask this here or should post new question? Because for my case  `const std::string PLANNING_GROUP = "crane_control"` then also `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface group("crane_control");`. Is that correct?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-04-27**:
No offense, but I think it would be best if you spent more time on finding the solution to this sort of question on your own. In your case, it takes no more than trying it out. Consider also that you are on a free Q&A site full of volunteers, which needs everyone's involvement to function properly. Your profile says that you have posted 164 questions and only 12 answers (even fewer of which are actual answers). Have you considered answering some questions and helping out some newcomers in return? How about subscribing to some tags (strongly recommended) and giving back to the community?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-04-27**:
ok. will answer some questions and help as much I can